# Trying to combine my partner's React code with my Node backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

Title explains it all, here's the context

So my partner has this index.js that he runs with `react-scripts start`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

import App from './components/App.jsx';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp.jsx';
import SignIn from './components/SignIn.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router path="/" history={browserHistory} >
        <Route path="/app" component={App} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And here I am on the back end with this app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const public_folder = '/public';
// app.use(express.static(__dirname + public_folder));

app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello, world!')
})

require('./server/routes')(app);

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Went into catch all *");
    // res.sendFile(__dirname + public_folder  + '/index.html');
});


module.exports = app;
```

I've learned some basic Node from following tutorials and I kinda understand how React works, but now my partner and I are at the stage where we need to merge our two halves. Can someone shed some light on what I need to do? I'm willing to provide more details as needed. Do we need to use Babel because we have jsx files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to render your React components in the backend and serve them with Express, you'll have to transpile your server-side code using Babel or some other transpiler. You can then use [renderToString](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) to create an HTML string and send that with your response.

Comment: Could you explain more? I'm not sure how exactly Babel works or really how to get started. That link you gave me doesn't really help me